# Interpreting basic contact and switch behaviour in a control system diagram

Tags: switches, control-system

This might sound a stupid question but in a control system using buttons and contacts I have a bit confusion when it comes to picturing the real device. As an example if we have the following diagram:

[image: ![enter image description here]]

There is Start button and NO contact called M. Now what is latching here? Button or the contact?

Is the Start button or the contact M latching type? I mean does it stay ON when I push and release my finger or I need to hold my finger pushed all the time to make it conduction current? Similarly for the contact M does it latch or does the current needs to pass all the time to energise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the green box and the purple box below: -

[image]

When the start button activates, the item I  have labeled "green M" is a coil that activates a contact (purple M) and so latches the circuit because the start button switch can be released and "purple M" keeps those nodes shorted.

Comment: Thanks it was opposite what I have thought. So the contacts are latching type but the buttons are not.

Comment: Start is a momentary normally open contact and stop is a momentary normally closed contact, both are likely to be push buttons.

Comment: I see. Just to be sure so is M in its nature latching? After purple M is closed If the green coil M disappears, would the purple M remain closed?

Comment: Green M can be regarded as a relay coil and purple M can be regarded as a contact associated with that relay coil. So, if one disappears, they both disappear. M isn't latching in nature but it is configured (by the schematic) to provide latching functionality in that circuit.

Comment: Great very clear thanks, trying to learn PLC from scratch.

Comment: @panicattack The contacts are not latching. The contacts are normal non-latching contacts and this is a circuit that makes them latch.

Comment: @ user253751 I got it. But if you look at the symbol do you understand it from the way it is drawn? In other words if they were latching contacts would they have different symbols?

Comment: If it were a latching relay it would likely have two coils (M1a and M1b or similar nomenclature).